# how to create environments in azure devops using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, rest

As explained on the URL,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

we should be able to list & create environments via invoke-webrequest. similar to how other REST objects work. But I get "Page not found"

did anyone try this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any issue calling

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/distributedtask/environments?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

[image]

Could you show how do you call this endpoint?

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?